# xsl:if with multiple checks ors?

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I get an error using the below code and I need to be able to compare a variable to four or more values.

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = ('Fixed Price Level of Effort','Fixed Unit Price','Firmed Fixed Price','Hybrid')">
```

I need to be able to check on multiple values

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is allowed in XSLT/XPath 2.0 and later so you would need to make sure you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime or Exselt. If you use an XSLT 1 processor you need to write `or` expressions e.g. `normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Fixed Price Level of Effort' or normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Fixed Unit Price' ...`

Comment: <xsl:if test="normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Fixed Price Level of Effort' or normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Fixed Unit Price' or normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Firmed Fixed Price' or normalize-space(@Contract_x0020_Type) = 'Hybrid')">

Comment: I still get
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


Correlation ID:f8ed4e9e-afd9-3036-4e51-d2f60539350e

Comment: It seems you have a closing `)` after the `'Hybrid'` which has no opening `(` and which seems is unnecessary, you can write a sequence of `or` expressions comparing strings without needing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks that worked...

Can you also use AND instead of OR and is Contains rather than = an option?

Is there a guide that docs all this?

Comment: XPath 1.0 is documented at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info has lots of links, for instance to the freely downloadable book https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm about XSLT and XPath.

Comment: Looking for a sample of the XSL:if test with CONTAINS

And can you use AND instead of OR?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it which is useful when there are dozens of values is

```
<xsl:variable name="values">
  <value>one</value>
  <value>two</value>
  ...
</xsl:variable>
```

then

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(@xxxx) = exslt:node-set($values/value)">...
```

XSLT 1.0 allows comparing against a set of nodes, but not against a set of strings (because there's no such thing in 1.0 as a set of strings). The only problem is the pesky exslt:node-set() extension function needed if you want to address into the content of a variable - you can avoid that by using an external document read using document() if you need to.

Comment: <xsl:if test="normalize-space(@SLED) = 'yes' and normalize-space(@Deal_x0020_Type) = 'Subcontractor'">

Comment: @pinkstonmatt There was no AND in my code so whatever you were trying wasn't what I gave you. Since I don't know what your code was and you haven't told me what the error was, it's hard to help.